# How to translate umbraco CMS in MVC application?

Tags: localization, umbraco

I have install my Umbraco on http://umb.local and and MVC project hosted http://umb.local/poc. I have tried to localize the text in MVC project using Umbraco APi but get the error like image

[image]

Could someone help me to fix it? or let me know which my section missing? such as configuration files + domain name, languages....

Thank you!

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're trying to do based on your description. Based on the screenshot you've sent, it looks like you're trying to use an Umbraco service in Razor, which isn't best practice. I'd recommend leaving this business logic to your controllers. Have you set up languages/locales on your home node(s) in Umbraco?

Comment: Thanks for your response, please skip the business logic code as screenshot, the error is that I could not call Umbraco API from an MVC Application, It always get error null exception 

such as the code above or if you inherit your view to *@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage*, you will get the error 

Hope you understand my issue 

Regards,

Comment: You're not making an API call, though. You're calling a service within the view layer, which won't work. Move these calls into the controller, set some breakpoints, and you should be able to see the service instantiate.